# Error checking array element to null

Tags: c, arrays, null, element

This question may be a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178804/how-to-see-if-an-element-is-null-in-an-array-in-c) or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793867/best-way-to-check-if-a-character-array-is-empty)

I am using C and trying to communicate with a device which works on serial communication. I am reading a single byte and storing it in an array and then checking the array element to `'\0'` (`0x00`). If it's `'\0'` then that means the data is now not available.

```
volatile int rxFlag = 0;
volatile int index = 0;

void function()             //event based function, whenever a byte is received
{
  Rx[index] = ReadUSART();     //reading a byte
  if(Rx[index] == '\0' )       //checking if its null 
  {
    rxFlag = 1;                //raise a flag

  }
  index++;                       //increment index
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the Rx:

[image]

In the image you can see the from `Rx[0]-Rx[24]` it contains data but  `Rx[25]` is a null terminator (`0x00`) and the `rxFlag` should be set to 1. But it is not set.

What is the another way of checking if the array element is `'\0'`.

Comment: Have you tried adding simple debug code to see what `Rx[25]` outputs?

Comment: What is the `index` value at the time you did the screenshot? It seems you received `25` chars, so last checked is `Rx[24]`....

Comment: You can simply check `if (!Rx[index]) rxFlag = 1;` as the *nul-character* `'\0'` has the numeric value of `0`.

Comment: I am sorry. I  have used the wrong code. its not a while(1) it a function which is an event based and is fired whenever the data is received. the problem I am facing is because when the byte received is the last byte, it is then received and index is incremented but as it was the last byte so the event is not fired again and thus it doesnt check for null char.

Comment: Could you show us the declaration of `rxFlag`?

Comment: @sunqingyao its `volatile int rxFlag = 0;`

Comment: Perhaps you should disable interrupts at the beginning of the function and enable them at the end of the function (or at least do it before and after `index++`), in order to ensure the persistence of `index` (i.e., ensure that `index++` is an atomic operation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo when assigning rxFlag.

```
rxFlag == 1;
```

should be

```
rxFlag = 1;
```

Comment: Good catch, it's funny how fallible the human mind is to glancing right over a `'=='` in place of a `'='`.

Comment: We've all been there :)

Comment: Your code looks fine from here, although I don't see what is reading/reacting to rxFlag.

Comment: The volatile statements are not necessary, unless you have something exotic like an interrupt routine updating them, in which case the compiler may do some unwanted optimisation without the volatile.

Comment: @PaulHK  I have used the volatile because its inside the interrupt.